# How to remove Pay later option in paypal checkout page. (we use python ,Django)

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox

[How to remove this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVfbG.png)

How to remove pay later option from paypal payment page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Paypal settings, open the `Additional Gateway Settings` part. If `Charge Customer Later` is enabled, toggle the value to `NO`.
Also, toggle `Show Pay Later Messaging` to `NO`.